# Background Image wont appear

Tags: html, css

I can't believe how hard I'm struggling on making the background image work. 
It should be easy, but for some reason it won't appear. I can do background-color:red; and the background will be red, but the background-image:url('backgroundpic.png') doesnt appear. Why is that?

CSS

```
 body
    {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    background-image: url('backgroundpic.png');
    }
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Site Demo</title>
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
      <link href="css/mainPage.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="header">
               <!--<div class='col-md-2'>-->
               <!--</div>
                  <div class="row row-centered">
                  <div class='col-md-6 col-md-offset-1 col-centered"'>
                  <div class='form-inline'>-->
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!--
         </div>


         </div>

         </div>
         -->
      <div class="container">
         <div class='underHeader'></div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">

      </div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
      <script src="js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--<script src="js/jquery.easing-1.3.js"></script>-->
      <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script> <script src="js/menu.js"></script> <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check the path to the image.  Perhaps it's a simple as adding `/` before the image name.

Comment: Use your console. You've probably used an invalid path; the console will show you the full path to where it's trying to find your file, which may help you out.

Comment: check the path of the image. `F12` on the browser will display console. There you can see if the browser is able to find the image or any other error.

Comment: Do the containers in your body have any defined height? If no, background image won't appear as there is no content.